# Make Background property work like an overlay

Tags: css, image, background, background-image

I know this is a bit weird question. but quite curious about this. Can we make background property work like an overlay? without using any extra html tag.

E.g,

`<img style="background: url('some image url to be overlayed on the actual image')" src="image src which will be hidden under the background image" alt="">`

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. No reason on earth to do that, but possible.

Comment: Ohh cool! then if you have solution please post it. it would be a great help to our community. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? I used padding for the size.

```css
img {
    padding-bottom: 35%;
    width: 500px;
    background: url(https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png);
    height: 0;
}
```

```html
<img  src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png" alt="" title="test">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but you would have to pad your overlay image to reveal its background:

```
#img{
    height: 20; // Front image height
    width: 20;  // Front image width
    padding: 50px 80px; // needs to be adjusted depend on your BG img size
    background-image: url('path_to_image');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```